# Prove that $ \mathcal{F}|_{F}=\left\{ A\cap F:A\in\mathcal{F}\right\}$ is a $ \sigma $ algebra over $F$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> **Question:** Let $ (\varOmega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}) $ be a probability space and $ F\in \mathcal{F} $ event such that $ \mathbb{P}\left(F\right)>0.$
>
> Define $ \mathcal{F}|_{F}=\left\{ A\cap F:A\in\mathcal{F}\right\}$ and prove that $ \mathcal{F}|_{F} $ is a $ \sigma $ algebra over $ F .$

Now, there are $3$ things I should prove.

1.$ F\in\mathcal{F}|_{F} $ - Thats obvious.

2.If $ \left(A_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}\in\mathcal{F}|_{F} $ a sequence of events, then $ \bigcup_{n}A_{n}\in\mathcal{F}|_{F} $ - I proved this also.

And the $3^{\text{rd}}$ thing that I cant understand is that

3. If $ A\in\mathcal{F}|_{F} $ then also $ A^{c}\in\mathcal{F}|_{F} $.

Now if $ A\in\mathcal{F}|_{F} $ then exists $B\in \mathcal{F} $ such that $ A=B\cap F $.

Thus $ A^{c}=B^{c}\cup F^{c} $, and I guess that here $ F^{c}=\emptyset $ because now $ F $ is my " $\varOmega$ " and in that case I should prove that $ B^{c}\in\mathcal{F}|_{F} $ meaning I have to find a set $ C \in \mathcal{F} $ such that $ B^{c}=C\cap F $ and Im not sure how to do it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $B^c\in\mathcal{F}$,
$$
F\setminus A =F\setminus (B\cap F)=F\setminus B=F\cap B^c \in \mathcal{F}|_F.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$F\backslash (B\cap F)=F\cap(B\cap F)^c=F\cap(B^c\cup F^c)=(F\cap B^c)\cup \underbrace{(F\cap F^c)}_{=\emptyset}=F\cap B^c\in\mathcal{F}|_F.$